# using dns to distribute version number or other info

Tags: dns

Just an idea...

Much software have a "check for updates" function.

Instead of having to write code to query a server at the distributor, and having to have a server capable of handling many requests, why not using dns?

Just doing a dns lookup of version.myprog.mydom.tld could give a version number, and the query would be cached upstream.

Of cause a proper framework for distributing the updated version of the software should be in place, but it could be somewhere in the cloud with filestorage, but no possibility of running something useful for version number distribution.

Any downsides?

Answer (score 1):

The only downside I can think of is actually caching: to enjoy the benefit of the distributed nature of DNS, you should have a non-zero TTL, so any updates you make to DNS would not be entirely real-time, but received by some clients later. Of course, this is only an issue if your updates do have to be real-time.

Another thing to be considered is that DNS limits the length of DNS labels and the characters that can be used, so any information communicated through DNS names must adhere to the [RFC requirements](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1035.txt). As for the version number retrieved from `version.myprog.mydomain.tld`, TXT RRs have been used for such purposes frequently.

Publishing non-DNS data through DNS is not entirely a new invention. For instance, [DNSBLs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNSBL) do this for more than a decade, which only confirms it can be done and done well.

Comment: A fairly long TTL would spread out the time when clients downloaded the new version, so a huge load when a new version came available will be avoided.

Comment: @LeifNeland: Yes, that can be an added benefit :)